# how to check default 3rd radio button in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Here is my code

```html
 <div id="radio-button">
    <input type="radio" name="colors11" value="1" id="myRadio21">Red color
    <input type="radio" name="colors12" value="2" id="myRadio22">black color
    <input type="radio" name="colors13" value="3" id="myRadio23">blue color
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="colors21" value="1" id="myRadio21">Red color
    <input type="radio" name="colors22" value="2" id="myRadio22">black color
    <input type="radio" name="colors23" value="3" id="myRadio23">blue color
</div>
<p>Click the "Try it" button to display the value of the value attribute of the radio button.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

and output default checked value 3 in js

Answer (score 1):

You can use the property `checked`
Like so:

```html
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="1" id="myRadio21" >Red color
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="2" id="myRadio22" >black color
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="3" id="myRadio23" checked>blue color
```

- Edit: you can then read or change this property with JavaScript if you wish. This is not necessary.
- Edit2: You need to set the name of your radios as the same for each one, otherwise checking one radio will not uncheck the rest.

Answer (score 1):

you dont need js. Probably `<input type="radio" name="colors11" value="1" id="myRadio21" class="active">` this class="active" enougth for you

Comment: class = `active` does nothing unless you have JS which looks for this class and checks it manually. The property which you are probably looking for is "`checked`" (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

The `checked` attribute pre-selects a certain radio button within one `name`-group:

```html
<div id="radio-button">
<label><input type="radio" name="colors1" value="1" id="myRadio21">Red color</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="colors1" value="2" id="myRadio22">black color</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="colors1" value="3" id="myRadio23" checked>blue color</label>
<br>
<label><input type="radio" name="colors2" value="1" id="myRadio21">Red color</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="colors2" value="2" id="myRadio22">black color</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="colors2" value="3" id="myRadio23" checked>blue color</label>
</div>
<p>Click the "Try it" button to display the value of the value attribute of the radio button.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```